# Background image not displaying on body

Tags: html, css

My CSS is not working I need it to be fixed
does not display and don't know why it has done this I'm new to coding HTML and CSS and want the image to go full screen.
I have tried everything and still not working.

```
body {

   background-image: "/folder/photo.gif";

}
```

Hope someone can help me out and find the answer.

Comment: maybe you can read more about CSS and background image before ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {

   background-image: url("/folder/photo.gif") no-repeat center center fixed;

}
```

This will work

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: That's ok, was no trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
body {background-image: url("/folder/photo.gif")}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
body {
   background-image: url("/folder/photo.gif");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help